# how to mark up a pdf text in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf

I am dealing with PDF Annotation right now and went through PDF Kit Reference. The problem is that the code given there for reference is too old and most of the syntax is changed also I am not getting ways to deal with.It gives error even if i add cocoa or pdfkit framework in my source code.I spent hours and hours to deal with this problem,but could not ressolve my this problem.

Can anybody help me with some example or some sort of code or something?

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your post with "ipad". PDFKit is not available for iOS.

What you could do is to [parse the PDF](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101) yourself to get the annotations. See the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101).

Comment: Thanks but i already went through that 2 links. But i am not getting specific response. Also I got the apple source code which was including the pdfkit,so thought that i may use that. Can you guide me any other way around?

Comment: Getting the annotations isn't part of the guide. You need to get yourself a copy of the PDF spec and know which tags you should be looking for. Then parse it the way it is done in the "Parsing PDF Content" section. It's a long and tedious process, I know. If you find an easier way, I am interested to know as well. :)

Comment: You could try offering a bounty to get people to notice your question.

Comment: I upvoted your question so you get additional rep. I think offering bounties require 50 rep minimum, so that option should be available now. Look for the `start a bounty` link under your post.

Comment: Thanks for your help Altealice but i surfed the FAQ and found that it need 75 score points to offer a bounty,so i can't ask for the same.